# Magento 2 Uncaught Error: Script error for: ko

Tags: javascript, magento, knockout.js, magento2

i'm facing this issue on checkout pages it keep loading with this error on console and another error for ko.js not found on the template root, i tried everything and i'm not using knockoutjs any where in the template there error gone only when i disable the template and use the default template

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: not sure that is knockout.. Knockout library is usually called with the full name i.e. knockout-3.4.0....js

Comment: do you have any suggestion what is this or how to fix it ? @Ray

Comment: sorry, havent worked with magento

Answer (score 0):

Run this command,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US
```